# How can I detect whether a ray hits the inside of a mesh?

Tags: three.js

I'm trying to use the RayCaster class to detect when a particle collides with a mesh. I do this by casting a ray in the direction of motion of the particle, and if the ray strikes the mesh, and the distance to the mesh is less than the distance the particle will travel in the current frame, a collision is detected.

Example code:

```
var whereAmI = particle.position;
var whereWasI = particle.previous;

var diff = new THREE.Vector3();
diff.subVectors(whereAmI,whereWasI);

var directionOfMotion = diff.clone().normalize();
var ray = new THREE.Raycaster( whereWasI, directionOfMotion );
var collisionResults = ray.intersectObjects( collidableMeshList );

if(collisionResults[0].distance < diff.length()){
  whereAmI.copy(whereWasI);
}
```

It works fine if the particle is outside the mesh. However, I'm running into a problem when the particle is inside a mesh. One way I thought about detecting these events was to make the mesh double sided, and cast a ray from the particle and see if it hits the inside of the mesh. So my question is: when casting a ray using RayCaster, is there a way to determine whether it strikes the inside of a mesh?

Thanks,
Aatish

Comment: When the mesh is two-sided, and if the point is outside - the number of intersects is even. If in - odd.

Comment: Thanks! That works beautifully.